# finger print reader not detected for Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E531 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I have installed fingerprint-gui according to their webpage.
The result of lsusb is:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:0397 Acer, Inc
```

So it seems my fingerprint device is Validity Sensors....

Then I ran `ls -la /dev/bus/usb/001/004` which gave the output:

```
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 3 Nov  3 12:38 /dev/bus/usb/001/004
```

So the permission seems correct?
But whenever I ran fingerprint-gui it says no device detected. Please help.
I have dual boot with Windows 7, there it works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

**Fprint Demo** is the application for finger print readers (including drivers) in Official Ubuntu Repository. Can install it with :

```
sudo apt-get install fprintd fprintd-doc libfprint-dev libfprint-dev libfprint0 aes2501-wy
```

Comment: Not able to detect device